# Change background image in items when hover a item in dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Hi i´m using bootstrap in one project and i have already a simple navbar header who already have two dropdown menu with items. But at the moment i need modify it to a sub-menu item with content associated like the example below, which when i hover one sub-menu item i need to change image to some image associated at the hover item. Example: Hover item 1 show a car, hover item 2 show other car, all inside the sub-menu items...

My code:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle page-scroll" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About Us</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#item1"><span class="item-text">Item 1</span></a>
    <div class="dropdown-items-divide-hr"></div>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#item2"><span class="item-text">Item 2</span></a>
    </div>
</li>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('item-text')[0].addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
document.getElementById('CAR IMG').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('CAR IMG2').style.display = 'none';
});
document.getElementsByClassName(''item-text')[1].addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
document.getElementById('CAR IMG2').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('CAR IMG').style.display = 'none';
});
```

make sure to include your  tags, you can add code wherever within these. Also make sure to replace CAR IMG and CAR IMG2 with the ids for the images, which means these  tags must have the actual ID attribute instead of just class.

Comment: reach out to me with any questions or concerns with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to load all the images on page load (to save bandwidth on mobile, and quickly load the page) one other solution would be to **set a data-attribute containing the image url you want to show for each link**.
Then, you could **change the style of your image container** with Javascript or Jquery to display the right image for the right mouse overed link.

Here is an example code:

```js
const defaultImage = 'http://lorempixel.com/g/400/400/';

$('[data-background-image]').on('mouseover', (e) => {
  const imageToShow = $(e.currentTarget).data('background-image');
  $('#my-background-image-container').css('background', `url(${imageToShow ? imageToShow : defaultImage})`)
})

$('[data-background-image]').on('mouseout', (e) => {
  $('#my-background-image-container').css('background', `url(${defaultImage})`)
})
```

```css
#my-background-image-container{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle page-scroll" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About Us</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#item1" data-background-image="http://lorempixel.com/g/500/200/"><span class="item-text">Item 1</span></a>
    <div class="dropdown-items-divide-hr"></div>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#item2" data-background-image="http://lorempixel.com/g/300/200/"><span class="item-text">Item 2</span></a>
    </div>
</li>

<div id="my-background-image-container">Content</div>
```